# FontAwesome Icons Spin only on mouseover?

Tags: icons, font-awesome

In font awesome how can i use this code : `<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>`   work on mouse over only?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of overriding the class, you can also just create another one for hover only:

```
.fa-spin-hover:hover {
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}


<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin-hover"></i>
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin-hover"></i>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xw7LH/1/

Note: if using Font-Awesome 4.2+ you may need to namespace the animation with "fa-":

```
.fa-spin-hover:hover {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to work anymore with FA 4.2.0. Any idea?

Comment: Nevermind, found a bug for this: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/3885

Comment: It will be awesome to pull request your class on FontAwesome Github ;)

Comment: Since Font-Awesome 4.2, you have to namespace the animation with "**fa-**" : `animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;`

Comment: Thanks @AlFoиceѫ, have updated the answer to include this

Answer (score 6):

You could also use javascript with the jquery library:

```
$('.fa-spinner').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('fa-spin');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-spin');
});
```

That would make it only spin on hover and reset back to its original position when its over - that being said it can look weird with some of the icons (I've only used it with the cog). For infinite spinning on hover you could just do this:

```
$('.fa-spinner').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('fa-spin');
});
```

jquery link: https://jquery.com/

Comment: I was wondering why no one suggested changing class till I found your answer. clean `jquery` approach with no `css` source modification.

Answer (score 0):

so make it work in my site css i change this

```
.fa-spin {
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}
```

with this

```
.fa-spin:hover {
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}
```

Comment: Change that, you must

Answer (score 0):

just use font awesome ccs file
for more details 
http://l-lin.github.io/font-awesome-animation/

they have detailed documentation on how to use the ccs

Answer (score 0):

in font awesome 5, I accidentally discovered that this is done by the new svg libraries that it implements
I do this:

```
.fa-spin-hover:hover svg {
-webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
-moz-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
-o-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;}
```

then it is assigned to the superior element and ready