# Icon spin on mouse-out

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome

I'm referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030259/fontawesome-icons-spin-only-on-mouseover) respectively [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw7LH/257/). I'd like to get the icon spinned in reverse on mouse-out. Any suggestions?

```
.fa-spin-hover:hover {
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s 1 linear;
    -moz-animation: spin 1s 1 linear;
    -o-animation: spin 1s 1 linear;
    animation: spin 1s 1 linear;
}

<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin-hover" style="font-size:100px"></i><br />
```

Comment: Do you mind a js solution?

Comment: Well, if there is a CSS only solution, that would be most welcome.

Comment: You *could* have a situation where the icon rotates to the left by default, and on hover it rotates to the right, but CSS does not have any equivalent of `mouseOut()`, so you would need JavaScript to **only** have it rotate the opposite way **after** leaving the hover.

Comment: Alright. And what if `mouseOut()` is executed while the `hover` animation is still in progress? Is there a way to stop the spin exactly at that point and start the reverse spin from that position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this. This is used little bit javascript and CSS.
You will be able to get some idea with this.

```js
$(".circle").mouseover(function(){
  $(".circle").removeClass("reverse").addClass("hover");
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(".circle").removeClass("hover").addClass("reverse");
});
```

```css
.hover {
  -ms-transform: rotateX(360deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transition:1s all;
  -webkit-transition:1s all;
  transition:1s all;
}

.reverse {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); 
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transition:1s all;
  -webkit-transition:1s all;
  transition:1s all;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  
</head>
<body>
  <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch circle" style="font-size:100px"></i>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries, happy coding :)